# Finding/filtering 2 dates of the same day

Tags: javascript, arrays, date-fns

I've got an array of dates for the month of July like so:

```
  const dates = [
    { date: '2023-07-01', available: true },
    { date: '2023-07-02', available: true },
    { date: '2023-07-03', available: true },
    { date: '2023-07-04', available: true },
    { date: '2023-07-05', available: true },
    { date: '2023-07-06', available: true },
    { date: '2023-07-07', available: true },
    { date: '2023-07-08', available: true },
    { date: '2023-07-09', available: true },
    { date: '2023-07-10', available: true },
    { date: '2023-07-11', available: true },
    { date: '2023-07-12', available: true },
    { date: '2023-07-13', available: true },
    { date: '2023-07-14', available: true },
    { date: '2023-07-15', available: true },
    { date: '2023-07-16', available: true },
    { date: '2023-07-17', available: true },
    { date: '2023-07-18', available: true },
    { date: '2023-07-19', available: true },
    { date: '2023-07-20', available: true },
    { date: '2023-07-21', available: true },
    { date: '2023-07-22', available: true },
    { date: '2023-07-23', available: true },
    { date: '2023-07-24', available: true },
    { date: '2023-07-25', available: true },
    { date: '2023-07-26', available: true },
    { date: '2023-07-27', available: true },
    { date: '2023-07-28', available: true },
    { date: '2023-07-29', available: true },
    { date: '2023-07-30', available: true },
    { date: '2023-07-31', available: true }
  ];
```

There is an `end` date of `2023-07-05` in the first element of the array and a `start` date in the second element of the array with the same `2023-07-05` date.
This means there is a checkout on the 5th and a checkin on the 5th so I would like to update the dates array above and set `available: false`.
I would like to do this anytime I see this pattern of 2 match dates such as the `2023-07-08`.

```
  const reserved = [
    { start: "2023-07-03", end: "2023-07-05" }, // check out 5th
    { start: "2023-07-05", end: "2023-07-08" }, // check in 5th, checkout 8th
    { start: "2023-07-08", end: "2023-07-10" }, // checkin 8th
    { start: "2023-07-18", end: "2023-07-20" }, // checkin 18th, check out 20th - ignore this completely, no overlap
    { start: "2023-07-22", end: "2023-07-24" }, // checkin out 24
    { start: "2023-07-24", end: "2023-07-26" }, // checkin 24
  ];
```

Any idea how I can accomplish this? I have tried a numerous amounts of filtering but I can never figure out the right pattern to update where there are
2 on the same day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply achieve this by using [`Array.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) and [`Array.lastIndexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) methods.

Live Demo **:**

```js
const dates = [
  { date: '2023-07-01', available: true },
  { date: '2023-07-02', available: true },
  { date: '2023-07-03', available: true },
  { date: '2023-07-04', available: true },
  { date: '2023-07-05', available: true },
  { date: '2023-07-06', available: true },
  { date: '2023-07-07', available: true },
  { date: '2023-07-08', available: true },
  { date: '2023-07-09', available: true },
  { date: '2023-07-10', available: true },
  { date: '2023-07-11', available: true },
  { date: '2023-07-12', available: true },
  { date: '2023-07-13', available: true },
  { date: '2023-07-14', available: true },
  { date: '2023-07-15', available: true },
  { date: '2023-07-16', available: true },
  { date: '2023-07-17', available: true },
  { date: '2023-07-18', available: true },
  { date: '2023-07-19', available: true },
  { date: '2023-07-20', available: true },
  { date: '2023-07-21', available: true },
  { date: '2023-07-22', available: true },
  { date: '2023-07-23', available: true },
  { date: '2023-07-24', available: true },
  { date: '2023-07-25', available: true },
  { date: '2023-07-26', available: true },
  { date: '2023-07-27', available: true },
  { date: '2023-07-28', available: true },
  { date: '2023-07-29', available: true },
  { date: '2023-07-30', available: true },
  { date: '2023-07-31', available: true }
];

const reserved = [
  { start: "2023-07-03", end: "2023-07-05" },
  { start: "2023-07-05", end: "2023-07-08" },
  { start: "2023-07-08", end: "2023-07-10" },
  { start: "2023-07-18", end: "2023-07-20" },
  { start: "2023-07-22", end: "2023-07-24" },
  { start: "2023-07-24", end: "2023-07-26" }
];

const reservedDatesArr = [];

reserved.forEach(obj => {
  reservedDatesArr.push(obj.start, obj.end)
})

const finalArr = dates.map(obj => {
  if (reservedDatesArr.indexOf(obj.date) !== reservedDatesArr.lastIndexOf(obj.date)) {
    obj.available = false;
  }
  return obj;
});

console.log(finalArr);
```

Comment: Works great Rohit. How would I track if I wanted to possibly track which one is checkIn and which one is checkOut:

```
  {
    "date": "2023-07-05",
    "available": false,
    "isCheckIn": true,
  },
  {
    "date": "2023-07-08",
    "available": false,
    "isCheckOut": true
  }
```

Comment: Actually, hmm, a checkin and a checkout is essentially the same thing, it'll be hard to differentiate between the 2. For example, the July 5th date has a check in which is a "start" date, and a checkout date which is the "end" date.

Comment: @jeffci as on single date (i.e. 2023-07-05) both `checkin` and `checkout` can happen. How it is possible to show either `checkin` or `checkout` ?

Comment: yah ignore that question - it really isn't possible to show because both are essentially the same; it's an overlap

Comment: for sure. Thanks for the help. I offered you a coffee a few days ago because you helped me before as well. I will do the same again because I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

You can run a loop starting from second element of array and keep checking the current element's start date with previous element's end date. If they match, update the date array.
Since the dates array is having sequential data, you can easily know at which index an update is required.

```
for(let idx=1; idx<reserved.length; idx+=1){
   if(reserved[idx].start === reserved[idx-1].end){
      // get the day from date string "YYYY-MM-DD" using split
      const datesIdx = Number(reserved[idx].start.split("-")[2]);

      // use the day as index and update dates array
      dates[datesIdx-1].available = false;
   }
}
```